# Active directory LDAP query in query

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to do query in active directory LDAP which gives me list of the groups that at least one of its member's given-name is Joe.
Do you know if it is even possible?
If it is - how do I do that?

Thanks alot and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LDAP in-chain matching rule to do this. For example, to find all the people named Joe in a group called All Users, you might do this:

`(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=All Users,OU=Groups,DC=contoso,DC=com)(givenName=Joe))`